# Will this P channel Mosfet switch work from a 3v3 GPIO

Tags: transistors, mosfet, stm32, mosfet-driver

I'm designing a circuit that I can reuse over again to switch loads of different kinds from around 8-30v and from around 0.5-15amp. Like a universal Solid state relay but I want my own custom circuit so I can put it on different PCBs.

I plan to interface this with a 3v STM32F GPIO

Here is my circuit:
[image]

Comment: Please use the MOSFET symbol for MOSFETs and the BJT symbol for BJTs. It will make your schematic much easier for others to understand.

Comment: And it will also make it immediately obvious why your circuit will not work.

Comment: The MMDT2907A is a dual PNP bipolar transistor, not a FET.

Comment: I don't know why that happened, I must have mistyped the part number. I have now edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the driving issue you have (needs a logic-level MOSFET or NPN BJT for Q2, as others have pointed out), your 0-30V is not valid. Nor is the 5A.

It will need to be at least 4.5V for the Rds(on) to be guaranteed. If it is less than 4.5V heating may even worse than expected.

Further, even at 4.5V, the power dissipation can be around 5W with a 5A current flowing, which is probably going to be destructive. (40-96°C/W using the PCB layouts given, which means the junction temperature could be well over the absolute maximum).

A better P-channel MOSFET would help. Also consider measuring the high voltage rail and inhibiting the drive if the voltage is too low.

Answer (score 0):

<s>MMDT2907A is not a N-channel mosfet as shown on the schematic. It is a PNP BJT transistor. So it won't work, the PNP transistor will never turn on. Its base will either be at 0V or at +3.3V, and it needs to be negative related to the emitter to turn on.</s>

Now, let's assume you actually put a N-channel mosfet as Q2 (you just did a mistake on the part number). In this case, it can work. When the GPIO is at 3.3V, assuming the gate threshold is low enough, Q2 will turn on, which will then turn on Q1 (the supply voltage on Q1 must be high enough). You could also use a NPN transistor (with an additional resistor at the base).

I also just realized that the resistor values are *way* too low. With a 30V supply, you need 140mA through Q2 and R1 (14V between the ground and the zener cathode, divided by 100Ohm). This is a huge power wasted. Just use some 470k for R1 and around 100k for R2. With this and a 8V supply, you get -6.6V at Q1 gate, and for a 30V supply -16V at the gate (of course) and a 140µA current through R2.

Now, if you need to select an appropriate N-channel mosfet part for Q2, you need to check the gate threshold voltage. It must be at most 3V for switching the required 140µA current. BSS138 will do it, now that you have edited the schematics.

Comment: Turning on Q2 fully would mean pulling D1 through 100 Ohms. At 16v(z), 30v-16v = 14v(r). 14v/100 Ohms = 140mA. 140mA * 14v = 1.96W(r). It had better be a 5W resistor. 140mA * 16v = 2.24W(z). D1 will [physically burn up and fail shorted](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-3/zener-diodes/) unless it is a massive, heatsinked one.

Comment: @rdtsc I had edited my post to show that already. You *have* to turn Q2 fully, anyway, the GPIO gives no choice. So the resistors values just need to be adjusted .

Comment: So if I used the values you said for R1 and R2, will the circuit work ok?

Comment: If you have 8V min as the mosfet supply, as you say in your question (and as opposed to the schematic which says 0-30V), it will work. However, switching 15Amp (as in your text) is unrealistic with this PFET. 5A (as in the schematic) could be ok with massive dissipation precautions: with the RDSon at 130mOhm, it makes RI² = 0.13*5*5 = 3.25W, which could be ok with a 1 inch² pad of 2oz copper (Rtja at 40°C/W as per datasheet). But if you need to switch such big currents, just take a beefier PFET. Even at 5A, something with RDSon at around 50mOhm is more reasonable, I think.

Comment: If you really need to switch 15A, you need a FET with RDSon around 10mOhm, with reasonable dissipation precautions (2.25W).